# fast looping and conditioning in R; insert new value in column based on the other column

Tags: r, loops, conditional-statements

I have massive data and I want to loop over data and insert the result into the new column which I named it `action2`:

my condition is based on `action` column:

```
if it contains "AA" OR "A1" then insert "As":
if it contains "BB" insert "Bs"
if it contains "AA" AND "C" then insert "AsC"
else insert the value in 'action' column 


df<- read.table(text="
user     action
1         AA
1         BB
1         ABCFF
1         A1B
2         AAB
2         BA1
2         AABC
3         M",header=T)

result df
user     action      action2
1         AA          As
1         BB          Bs
1         ABCFF       ABCFF
1         A1B         As
2         AAB         As    
2         BA1         As          
2         AABC        AsC
2         M           M
```

how can I do it in R? (prefarably using dplyr library)

Comment: if it needs faster option, do you want data.table

Comment: there is one doubt, for 'AABC', it can match to 'AA'.  are you looking for substring match or fixed match

Comment: @akrun I am looking for substring matching, Tx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `case_when` will work, though as @akrun commented, a `data.table` solution might be faster if you need speed.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(action2 = case_when(
    grepl("AA.*C|C.*AA", action) ~ "AsC",
    grepl("A[A1]", action)       ~ "As",
    grepl("BB", action)          ~ "Bs",
    TRUE                         ~ action)
  )
#   user action action2
# 1    1     AA      As
# 2    1     BB      Bs
# 3    1  ABCFF   ABCFF
# 4    1    A1B      As
# 5    2    AAB      As
# 6    2    BA1      As
# 7    2   AABC     AsC
# 8    3      M       M
```

(In order to get this to work as-is, I converted your current `action` to `character` from a factor. Since your data is just toy/sample, it may not be a factor for your real data.)